# How to create an ordered list of keys based on their value in a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, unique

I'm quite stuck with this problem in Python and I'm pretty sure it should be pretty easy to solve.

Please find this dict example:

```
d = {
    "a": "abc1",
    "b": "abc1",
    "c": "abc2",
    "d": "abc3",
    "e": "abc3",
    "f": "abc3",
    "g": "abc4"
}
```

Now I want a to create a list where 'a' till 'g' will be put in an order that is mixing up abc values as much as possible, but I require all keys in the list so:

```
['a','c','d','g','b','e']
```

Then 'f' will be left over (because e also has value abc3) and can be added to a leftover list.

I tried the following:

```
s = []
for x in d: 
    if len(s) < 1:
        s.append(x)
    if d[s[-1]] is not d[x]:
        s.append(x)
```

But this will produce just:

```
['a', 'c', 'd', 'g']
```

I need to go back and try again until no solutions are possible.

Thanks a lot for your time and suggestions!

Comment: `d` also has the value `abc3` doesn't it, so why is `e` included?  also why is this tagged [tag:random]

Comment: I think no two following keys may have the same value.

Comment: Thank you. It is included because the value of b is (before e) is abc1. So that list will correspond with the values abc1,abc2,abc3,abc4,abc1,abc3 (then f is left because it also has 3). The goal is to not have 2 keys with the same value after each other, but also spread the keys as much as possible until there are no options. I will remove the tag.

Comment: so would `d a e b f c g` be a valid output?

Comment: @SamMason technically yes, but how would you obtain it?

Answer (score 1):

This is the first code I got working. And now it also removes f. Any other ideas?

```
d = {
    "a": "abc1",
    "b": "abc1",
    "c": "abc2",
    "d": "abc3",
    "e": "abc3",
    "f": "abc3",
    "g": "abc4"
}

list_number = {}
key_lists = []

for key, value in d.items():
    if value in list_number:
        index = list_number[value] = list_number[value] + 1
    else:
        index = list_number[value] = 0
    if index < len(key_lists):
        key_lists[index].append(key)
    else:
        key_lists.append([key])
result = []
remaining = []
for key_list in key_lists:
    if not result or len(key_list) > 1:
            result.extend(key_list)
    else:
        remaining.extend(key_list)
print("# Result", result)
print("# Remaining:", remaining)
# Result ['a', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'b', 'e']
# Remaining: ['f']
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tested this on my dict and it does the trick for 95%. It is not entirely what I was looking for, but this helps a lot already.

Comment: So, I assume you also want to include f in your list somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```py
d = {
    "a": "abc1",
    "b": "abc1",
    "c": "abc2",
    "d": "abc3",
    "e": "abc3",
    "f": "abc3",
    "g": "abc4"
}

counted = {}
done = False
while not done:
    # Assume done
    done = True
    last_value = None
    for key, value in d.items():
        if key not in counted and value != last_value:
            done = False
            last_value = value
            # Add the key to the result dict, the value 1 is arbitrary
            counted[key] = 1

result = list(counted)
print(f"Result: {result}")
```

Output:

```
Result: ['a', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'b', 'e', 'f']
```

**Notes**

- The `counted` dictionary will have the same keys as in `d`, but ordered the way we want. The values are arbitrary. I could have used a list, but the look up `key not in counted` will take longer if `d` is a large dictionary.
- The while loop will keep going until we added all keys to the `counted` dictionary.
- The inner for loop will go through the keys/values and only add those keys that are qualified by the `if` conditions.

Comment: Please note that in the end you can't include f as Slacker asked.

Comment: I don't know how difficult it is to add f to a remaining keys list.

Answer (score 0):

The questions I was asking up top were to turn your informal question into something that can be easily implemented in code. In this case, you seem be asking:

- every key from `d` should appear in the output, if possible
- it must not follow a key that has the same value

To solve this it helps to work out what constraints we can impose to make the algorithm easier.  In this case the difficulty seems to be those keys that share the same value.  This implies we should try and deal with those first, hence my question whether `d a e b f c g` is a valid solution.  I saw that `abc3` appeared the most, and so I started with that.

When turning this into code, a key concept is the [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).  An implementation of this is available in the standard [heapq](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) Python module.

It's then a relatively simple matter of writing the code and handling the edge cases.  I've put quite a few comments in that try to explain what it's doing:

```
from heapq import heapify, heappop, heappush
from collections import defaultdict
from random import shuffle, random

def fn(d: dict, *, randomize=True):
    # get items from dictionary
    if randomize:
        # add random value to keep heap random
        mk = lambda l: (-(len(l) + random()), l)
        items = list(d.items())
        # ensure keys under each value are randomized
        shuffle(items)
    else:
        mk = lambda l: (-len(l), l)
        items = d.items()
    # collect all the keys together under their values
    acc = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in items:
        acc[v].append(k)
    # build a priority queue, longest list of keys first
    queue = [mk(ks) for _, ks in acc.items()]
    heapify(queue)
    # pull out distinct values
    result = []
    while queue:
        # add an item from the longest list
        _, ks = heappop(queue)
        result.append(ks.pop())
        # if there are other keys available
        if queue:
            # add an item from second longest list
            _, ks2 = heappop(queue)
            result.append(ks2.pop())
            if ks2:
                # push remaining items back onto the queue
                heappush(queue, mk(ks2))
        elif ks:
            # no other keys available and this one has entries, so we're stuck
            break
        # push remaining items back onto the queue
        if ks:
            heappush(queue, mk(ks))
    # done
    return result

# test
fn({"a": 1, "b": 1, "c": 2, "d": 3, "e": 3, "f": 3, "g": 4}, randomize=False)
```

which prints:

```
['f', 'b', 'e', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'g']
```

Because you originally tagged [random](/questions/tagged/random), I made it randomize the output when `randomize=False` isn't passed.  This is what it does by default, so for example, `fn(d)` might give:

```
['d', 'a', 'f', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'g']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import zip_longest, chain

d = {
    "a": "abc1",
    "b": "abc1",
    "c": "abc2",
    "d": "abc3",
    "e": "abc3",
    "f": "abc3",
    "g": "abc4"
}

# Create and populate default dict of "value": [key1, key2, ...]
vk = defaultdict(list)
[vk[v].append(k) for k,v in d.items()]

# Zip the values together column by column and remove any columns
# with only one key because this means it's repeating.
ll = [c for c in [[b for b in a if b is not None]
            for a in zip_longest(*vk.values())]
                if len(c) > 1]

# Flatten the list of lists into list of keys.
keys = list(chain(*ll))

print(keys)
```

This returns:

```
['a', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'b', 'e']
```

The way this works is by first inverting the values and keys of `d` into the `vk` defaultdict:

```
> vk = defaultdict(list)
> [vk[v].append(k) for k,v in d.items()]
> vk
defaultdict(list,
        {'abc1': ['a', 'b'],
         'abc2': ['c'],
         'abc3': ['d', 'e', 'f'],
         'abc4': ['g']})
```

This next step does a couple of things.  The `zip_longest()` function returns this:

```
> list(zip_longest(*dd.values()))
[('a', 'c',   'd', 'g'),
 ('b',  None, 'e',  None),
 (None, None, 'f',  None)]
```

The `[b for b in a if b is not None]` bit removes all the `None` entries so now you are left with:

```
> [[b for b in a if b is not None] for a in zip_longest(*dd.values())]
[['a', 'c', 'd', 'g'], ['b', 'e'], ['f']]
```

From this we only keep any sub-lists that are longer than a single element with `len(c) > 1`. This is because a single element must be a repeat of the row above it (see the `list(zip_longest(*dd.values()))` structure). This leaves us the list of lists `ll`.

```
> ll
[['a', 'c', 'd', 'g'], ['b', 'e']]
```

We flatten that with `chain(*ll)` which returns an iterator that we turn into a list of our original keys that we can do what we want:

```
> keys = list(chain(*ll))
> print(keys)
['a', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'b', 'e']
```